# Easy FindMaximum returns a wrong answer

Tags: mathematical-optimization, regions

`FindMaximum` in region is a new function in mma10,but when I tried the following example:

```
region = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {10, 0}, {10, 5}, {5, 5}, {5, 10}, {0, 10}}]
FindMaximum[{x + y, {x, y} \[Element] region}, {x, y}]
```

Mathematica 10.1 returns

```
{10., {x -> 5., y -> 5.}}
```

We can easily know that it is wrong.
What's the story?

Comment: `NMaximize[{x + y, {x, y} \[Element] region}, {x, y}]` however does work?

Comment: You can also use `Maximize[{x + y, {x, y} \[Element] region}, {x, y}]` for this case as well.

Comment: @blochwave I have tried that,but I wonder why FindMaximum "goes wrong".

Comment: so am I - have you tried specifying an initial starting point for `x` and `y`?

Comment: The point {5,5} is a local maxima in the region when approached along the line x==y

Comment: @BobHanlon why then, if you specify a starting point of e.g. `{{x, 9.9}, {y, 4.9}}`, does MMA still head off in the direction of `{5,5}`?

Comment: @blochwave I can't agree with you more.

Comment: @blochwave - I have no idea.

Comment: @BobHanlon me neither! Puzzling :-)

Comment: @xzczd can you help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Defining just one of the points of the region with a decimal point helps, suggesting that the method chosen by `FindMaximum` for integer coordinates is a perhaps a linear programming method, and gets stuck at the observed `{5, 5}`.

Instead one can do:

```
region = Polygon[{{0., 0}, {10, 0}, {10, 5}, {5, 5}, {5, 10}, {0, 
     10}}];
result = Last@FindMaximum[{x + y, {x, y} \[Element] region}, {x, y}]
(* {x -> 10., y -> 5.} *)

Show[ContourPlot[x + y, {x, y} \[Element] region], 
 Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{x, y} /. result]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: It's obvious that we can't know how mma works unless we are members of Wolfram Research.It's a pity that mma returns a unexpectedly result.So how to get a good answer is just a technical task in some extents.