# Why does EvaluationMonitor in FindMaximum only work for some regions?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, regions

This has come about after trying to understand what was going on with [this question about `FindMaximum` and regions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/81065/easy-findmaximum-returns-a-wrong-answer). My first thought in that scenario was to set-up `EvaluationMonitor` and `StepMonitor` to see which points in the region Mathematica visited as it tried to find the maximum.

```
$Version
(* 10.1.0  for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 24, 2015) *)

(* from the linked question *)
region = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {10, 0}, {10, 5}, {5, 5}, {5, 10}, {0, 10}}];

(* build up a list of regions to test *)
regionlist = {Disk[], Triangle[], Rectangle[], Parallelogram[], region};

(* use FindMaximum *)
result =
 Last@FindMaximum[{x + y, {x, y} \[Element] #}, {x, y}, 
     EvaluationMonitor :> Print["Evaluation: ", x, ",", y],
     StepMonitor :> Print["Step: ", x, ",", y]] & /@ regionlist

graphics = 
  MapThread[
   Show[ContourPlot[x + y, {x, y} \[Element] #1], 
     Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], 
       Point[{x, y} /. #2]}]] &, {regionlist, result}];

GraphicsRow[graphics]
```

[image]

When I run this code, for `Disk[]` I get a list of steps and evaluations at various values of `x` and `y`. But when I try using either monitor combined with a region other than `Disk[]`, I get no output. **Why is this?**

Comment: Possibly related: when I try discretizing the regions, I get a `FindMaximum::elemc: Unable to resolve the domain or region membership condition` message.

Comment: @2012rcampion is that for all regions, including `Disk[]`?

Comment: Since the objective function is linear, probably the solution for all these regions except `Disk[]` comes from a linear programming method, so there are no iterations to monitor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to a comment from @ilian, I came back to the question:

> Since the objective function is linear, probably the solution for all
>   these regions except `Disk[]` comes from a linear programming method, so
>   there are no iterations to monitor

And indeed, that's we see. Change the function to e.g. $x^{2}+y^{2}$ and `EvaluationMonitor`/`StepMonitor` works a treat.

Alternatively, defining the region with machine-precision numbers also works, i.e.

```
region = Polygon[{{0., 0.}, {10., 0.}, {10., 5.}, {5., 5.}, {5., 10.}, {0., 10.}}]
```

and indeed doing this seems to solve the problem in [the related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/81065/easy-findmaximum-returns-a-wrong-answer).